# Unable to show messages

Tags: ros, tutorial, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen similar questions, but they do not solve my problem.
http://answers.ros.org/question/187071/cannot-load-message-class-for-are-your-messages-built/

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Indigo.

If I like my messages to be shown by the command: rosmsg show only the standard ROS-messages are showing up. (Using tab) If I use the name of the msgs like rosmsg show ATestMsg.msg the message can not be found. (error: Could not find msg 'ATestMsg')

My messages can't be found. I think I've done everything the same as in the tutorial explained. Neither source devel/setup.bash nor catkin clean and rebuild seem to solve the problem.

My CMakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(a_vector_field)
## Use C++11
## add_definitions(--std=c++11)
## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  visualization_msgs
  magnetic_controller
  mag_msgs
  tf
  roscpp
   rospy
   std_msgs
   message_generation
)
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
include_directories(include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${mag_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_message_files(
   FILES
   CurrentsStamped.msg
   FieldStamped.msg
   ATestMsg.msg
   SecondTestMsg.msg
 )
add_service_files(
  FILES
  get_magnetic_field.srv
  load_calibration_file.srv
  set_magnetic_field.srv
  set_magnetic_field_gradient.srv
  #set_position.srv
)
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
   mag_msgs
)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
    include
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
  CATKIN_DEPENDS 
    mag_msgs
    message_runtime
    roscpp
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
#  DEPENDS 
)
include_directories(
  include
 ${mag_msgs}
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${armadillo_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${blas_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${lapack_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
#add_dependencies(mag_msgs ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
###########
## Build ##
###########
add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}_OTHER_FILES ALL WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} SOURCES ${EXTRA_FILES})
## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
## Declare a C++ executable
##install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
##        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/${PROJECT_NAME}_node.cpp
  src/magneticfield.cpp
  src/avectorfield.cpp
)
## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES}
${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
 ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QT_LIBRARIES})
add_library(armadillo src/magneticfield.cpp src/avectorfield.cpp )
install(TARGETS armadillo #blas lapack
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
        PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

And my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>a_vector_field</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The a_vector_field package</description>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>mag_msgs</build_depend> 
<buildtool_depend>mag_msgs</buildtool_depend> 
<build_depend>magnetic_controller</build_depend>
 <build_depend>libarmadillo-dev</build_depend>
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
 <run_depend>magnetic_controller</run_depend>
  <run_depend>mag_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>visualization_msgs</run_depend>
  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

Did somebody ever occur similar problem? For any solution I would be very thankful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265569/unable-to-show-messages/) by [TobiasE](https://answers.ros.org/users/30963/tobiase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could solve the problem - it seems to be a very trivial one.

The resourcing "source devel/setup.bash" needs to be done in every console window.

---

Originally posted by [TobiasE](https://answers.ros.org/users/30963/tobiase/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeanpolochon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27330/jeanpolochon/) on 2017-07-06**:
you can add it to your .bashrc file

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-06**:
@TobiasE: thanks for reporting back.

Could I ask you to just *accept* your own answer instead of closing the question? We try to avoid closing questions here on ROS Answers, as it's not visible from the question list why that was done. An answered question gets a green checkmark.

**Comment by [TobiasE](https://answers.ros.org/users/30963/tobiase/) on 2017-07-06**:
Ok, sorry about that. I can not do that as it requires more than 10 points.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-06**:
No need to apologise. I've accepted it for you.